# my code won't write text to table cells

Tags: javascript, php

Second question today, but It's really not working. 
I've got a shopping card with a table at the left and one at the right, left are the products you can buy, right the pruducts that are on your card. The code worked but if you clicked twice on a product it added two new rows so I edited my code. Somehow when I click on it now I won't get any result. (oh, and I've put my code between  tags, earlier today is was in my onClick-function)

```
<script>
function addToTable(productName, productPrice){
    var table = document.getElementById('cardtable');
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    alert(rowCount);
    for(var i =0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var text = currentRow.cells[0].innerText;

        if(text == '$productnames[$i]') {
            var currentValue = parseInt(row.cells[3].innerHTML);
            var newValue = currentValue + 1;
            currentRow.cells[2].innerText = newValue;
        }else {
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell1.id ='cardlefttd';
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.id ='cardcentretd';
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            cell3.id ='cardrighttd';

            cell1.innerHTML = '$productnames[$i]';
            cell2.innerHTML = '$iprice';              
            cell3.innerHTML = 1;
            }
    }
}
</script>
```

The next code is in PHP, and it makes a table with data from a MySQL database (it worked fine!)

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($productnames); $i++) {
$iprice = number_format((float)$productprices[$i], 2, ',', '');

echo (
    "<tr id='producttablerow' onclick='addToTable($productnames[$i],$iprice)'>
        <td id=productlefttd>$productnames[$i]</td>
        <td id=productrighttd>$iprice</td>
    </tr>"
    );
```

}

So the problem is, since I put the for-statement instead of only what's now in the else there's nothing running. 
I know there's still another mistake in the code but it should just run. (multiple new lines are made if else is the case)

Comment: Looks like you're giving the same "id" value to multiple elements, and that's going to cause problems. "id" values must be unique across a page.

Comment: I am not sure, but, I think you should put curly brackets in this line of code `<td id=productlefttd>{$productnames[$i]}</td>`

Comment: @pointy kan I use classes?

Comment: Yes you can use classes.

Comment: thanks, I'll use classes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 echo "... onclick='addToTable($productnames[$i],$iprice)' ... "
```

This will produce invalid javascript code. You have to wrap Strings into `'`:

```
 echo "... onclick=\"addToTable('$productnames[$i]',$iprice)\" ... "
```

This is now valid Javascript, but invalid PHP(-usage). To produce valid PHP: Within a `"`-String, you can use variables - but not method calls or array accesses. Use:

```
 echo "... onclick=\"addToTable('".$productnames[$i]."',$iprice)\" ... "
```

Comment: It´s adding it to the table again, so that´s a development :p Problem is, i get this into the table now: $productnames[$i] $iprice 1, so it's not picking the php variables this way.

Comment: Oh i got it, I'll put the right code here in a few minutes

Comment: @RikNijhuis Same reason. Escape the variables properly. :)

Comment: It's running now, but my float iprice variable is now an integer in my table, kan you tell me why?

Comment: @RikNijhuis You are using `number_format` to format your price. You pass the `,` as a decimal seperator so, when the value is `2.33`, the generated javascript call would be `addToTable('aString',2,33)` - the generated javascript is *thinking* you are going to pass 3 arguments, so your second parameter is `2`, instead of `2.33` . Either stay with the `.` as decimal seperator (`addToTable('aString',2.33)` would be fine), or pass the value as string also. It's always a good idea to perform *formating* the moment you are presenting the value to a user - otherwhise stick to raw data formats.